# Best way to add/alter fields in a form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following model

```py
class customer_prices(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.FloatField()
    function = models.TexField()
     .
     .
     (10 more fields)
```

The fields shown in the homepage is only `price` thus the other fields are assigned manually, based on the values in a dataframe returned by a self-written `some_util_function()` e.g

```py
@login_required
def add_price(request):
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            df = some_util_function(cleaned_data["price"])
            form.user_id = user.id
            form.image= df["image"] 
             .
             .
            form.save()

            messages.success(request, "Price added")

            return redirect("my_html")

    return render(...)
```

As we can see each form-field is updated by `form.field=df["field"]` thus I wonder, if there is another (better way) of doing that?

I have thought about the two following ways:

1. Instead of `form.field=value` then `form.cleaned_data["field"] = value`
2. Since I have all the data in a dataframe, simply push that dataframe to the given DB e.g `df.to_sql("my_table_name")`.

I know (2) is working, but I think it's better to keep the database changes to Django, and not some mix between pushing data self and let Django handle it.

Comment: Normally you do that in the `clean` method of the form. That is what *cleaning* is all about.

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to Django, I did not know that we are able to write a `clean` method.